# Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

How to install migration tool ?I am trying to install this (https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) tool.
I am stuck in below place.

[image]

Comment: For which version of magento you are installing

Comment: Then i don't think you will get any according to to screen shot it will take some time and will install it.

Comment: If you are getting issue paste error you are getting or error screen shot

Comment: @AmanAlam Thanks.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBak9.png

Comment: This is problem of your server you should consult regarding this with your server guys

Comment: Thanks @AmanAlam. I am using AWS. What should I do ?

Comment: How much RAM you have? Also how much memory limit is assigned to php

Comment: @AmanAlam, How know how much RAM I have ?

Comment: You can check ram by checking instance i.e if you are using micro then it will be 1GB tell me name of the instance

Comment: Thanks @AmanAlam. I am using `t2.micro` instance. How to increase RAM ?

Comment: You can't increase ram for existing instance you must need to change instance for it.

Comment: Should I create new instance ?

Comment: Yes with proper ram size at least 2GB

Comment: Thanks @AmanAlam. How to know current RAM size ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/